# javascripts get json will show Unexpected token '&'

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a question,
That is where I pass json string to a MVC ViewModels which call "showModel.cs"
For example, my json will be like: `[{"Name": "Emma", "Age": "20"}]`

VisualizationController.cs

```
string str_json = '[{"Name": "Emma", "Age": "20"}]';
StringBuilder js = new StringBuilder(str_json);

model.json = js;
```

showModel.cs

```
public class showModel
{
    public StringBuilder json { get; set; }
}
```

And today I want to use javascripts to call that json which is in showModel.cs, 
The json will be like: `[{\\"Name\\": \\"Emma\\", \\"Age\\": \\"20\\"}]`

But the javascripts will display `[{&quot;Name&quot;: &quot;Emma&quot;, &quot;Age&quot;: &quot;20&quot;}]`

Show.cshtml

```
<script>
    var js = JSON.parse(@Model.json);
</script>
```

And then the web will show **Unexpected token '&'**

So, how can I do ?? Thanks u guys:)

Comment: I believe something has been missed in your question. Can you check again.

Comment: sorry, i add somethig miss ti my question, @AbhishekGowda28

Comment: `string str_json = '[{"Name": "Emma", "Age": "20"}]';` is entirely invalid C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

`var js = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Model.json)');`